# xdsoft datetimepicker range between not working with d/m/Y H:i

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a textbox with datetimepicker. the min date of textbox is set from value of another textbox.

Let say the textbox, 'txtTimeINReadOnly' has value '02/07/2014 11:37', i want to set mindate of calender bound to another textbox, say 'txtTimeOUT' as txtTimeINReadOnly value. 
My code goes like this

```
var minDateVal = $('#txtTimeINReadOnly').val();
            alert(minDateVal);

            $('#txtTimeOUT').datetimepicker({
                //mask: '9999/19/39 29:59',
                value: todayDate,
                format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
                onShow: function (ct) {
                    this.setOptions({
                        minDate: minDateVal
                        , formatDate: 'd/m/Y H:i'
                    });
                }
            });
```

But the minDate is always set as the current date.
But if i give the date directly to code, like this

```
this.setOptions({
     minDate: '02/07/2014 11:37'
     , formatDate: 'd/m/Y H:i'
     });
```

Its working correctly. The alert also give the value of txtTimeINReadOnly as 02/07/2014 11:37. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution:

On file jquery.datetimepicker.js v2.2.9 change :

line 913 maxDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strtodate(options.maxDate);
to: maxDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDateTime(options.maxDate);

line 918: minDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strtodate(options.minDate);
to: minDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDateTime(options.minDate);

[see this link](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/82)